# Are down-votes being misused?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I'm amazed about the mood on this StackExchange site. Where people are so nervous and use down-votes as a gun. I wonder if some tuning shouldn't be made to the logic of down-votes.

Comment: Hi, Rabskatran - only time will tell what the outcome of the beta will be, but it sounds like you're primarily concerned about down-voting... Can you be more specific? What have you seen that concerns you?

Comment: You see, I'm already downvoted on this stupid question. Just as people are so frustrated on the other SE sites not to be able to use the downvote button that they finally found a place where they can let go their energy :)-

Comment: @Rabskatran: I *suspect* you were down-voted because you didn't do a very good job of detailing the problem you're here to discuss... Which is what down-votes are *for*! Spend some time elaborating...

Comment: See my comment on the Borror answer... I'm concerned about the fact that the war of downvoting will not lead to the right answer but just the biggest tribe to impose his view on the question.

Comment: No offense to have been down-voted.

Comment: An idea would be that a comment should be mandatory for down-vote. It's not expensive, but at least, you've to argue why you act like this, no ?

Comment: @Rabskatran: a down-vote is primarily a message to *other readers*; a comment is primarily a message to *the author*. Sometimes they're both useful, but not always. Mandating comments tends to generate noise and unnecessary discussion... Those who feel they have something to say will generally do so, whether or not they vote.

Comment: Downvoting without comment is anonymous, which has advantages, and disadvantages. This particular question should be more concrete, IMHO, but I often receive anonymous down-votes, and of course I don't learn much, that way. I understand the frustration.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'm just skepict about the fact that this site will allow non-main stream (but correct) thoughts on a subject to rise as the "right answer".

Comment: @Rabskatran: if there was only a magic formula for identifying "correct but unpopular"... The best we can do is try to encourage good sources over unsubstantiated opinion in answers, and avoid troll-baiting in questions.

Comment: You're right. And again, this is the warmup. Maybe this will cool down on the long run.

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem is the opposite. People don't downvote enough. Downvoting poor posts is a way to ensuring we maintain an high level of quality, and we need to maintain high quality to succeed.

Comment: I still a rookie on this site, but what I've seen is more the pro downvoting the anti and the anti downvoting the pro. So the tie is just a mater of numbers, not correctness.

Comment: @Rabskatran: Do you mean on meta? If so, that's not misusing downvotes. Quite the opposite, **[downvoting on meta means "I disagree."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16465/downvoting-opinions/16467#16467)**

Comment: This question is NOT about meta.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm just skepict about the fact that this site will allow non-main stream (but correct) thoughts on a subject to rise as the "right answer".

If that's your issue than your problem isn't much about downvoting. It's also about failure to upvote certain answers.

Democracy isn't a perfect system but it's the best we have. If you want more answers that go against the general consensus write some well sourced answers. Try to convince some people who are able to write a well sourced defense of contrarian positions to come and visit this website.

Vote up contrarian answers that are well sourced.

Comment: And also to that problem I'd say, how do you know it's correct? If the case is made well (sources, etc.) then I wouldn't worry about downvotes, I think the upvotes would start flowing in.